# Redis SET with option, without expiry

Tags: redis

I'm writing a library that stores keys in Redis or Memcached. To keep it generic, I'd like to use `SET` for all my set operations, but I'm struggling to find an expiry value that equates to "don't expire". Is there a sentinel value I can send?

For example, If there's an expiry of 100, I'd like to send:

```
SET myKey myValue ex 100 NX
```

but if there's no expiry, I'd prefer to do

```
SET myKey myValue ex -1 NX
```

rather than

```
SETNX myKey myValue
```

Interestingly, there doesn't appear to be any way to do the equivalent of a `SET` using the `XX` option without an expiry.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just send the set command *without* an EX option.

```
Set key value NX
```

Comment: Not sure how OP missed this, it's literally here in the docs: http://redis.io/commands/SET

Comment: Apologies for not explaining the downvote. The question was how to set _with an option_ but without expiry. `SET key value` will set the key, but doesn't give any control over XX/NX.

Comment: @rossmcf added NX as the documentation lists. The use of the EX or PX options is independent of any use of NX or XX.

Comment: @TheRealBill Thanks I'll check that out. What I'm seeing may be a limitation of Predis, the client library I'm using.

Comment: Hazaah! Thanks @TheRealBill!